# gnuplot : variable paths to data file in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

I would like to plot multiple curve on the same graph using a for loop. Each data file (named stat_coupe) is located in a different folder (fwal055wal055/rep16/ and fwal055wal055_c2/rep20/). fwal055wal055 and fwal055wal055_c2 correspond to names of simulation. First, I need to get a previous result, a single number (Utau), in other files (named file_fwal055wal055 and file_fwal055wal055_c2). This is successfully done thanks to the command awk. The result depend on the file: Utaufwal055wal055=10.5 and Utaufwal055wal055_c2=12.2.

Then I need to divid the 1st column of the file stat_coupe corresponding to the path fwal055wal055/rep16/ by the value of Utaufwal055wal055 and do the same thing for the file stat_coupe corresponding to the path fwal055wal055_c2/rep20/ with the value of Utaufwal055wal055_c2. Moreover, each plot should have a specific format which depend on the type of simulation run (fwal055wal055 or fwal055wal055_c2).

The presented problem is reduced to 2 simulations fwal055wal055 and fwal055wal055_c2 and 1 plot but I have about 20 simulations and 15 various graphs to plot that is why I would like to use the for loop.

To summary at each iteration I have:

- a specific format,
- a specific path,
- a specific value of Utau

I want to indicate the wright format, path and value of Utau at each iteration of the for loop. The solution I propose below successfully permits to obtain the value of Utau for each simulation but the code @path_.i and @format_.i does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash
for elem in fwal055wal055 fwal055wal055_c2;
do
  Utau[${elem}]=$(awk 'FNR==5{print $1}' file_$elem)
done

gnuplot -persist  <<-EOFMarker
format_fwal055wal055='pt 1 ps 1.0 lc 0 title "WALE"'
format_fwal055wal055_c2='pt 2 ps 1.0 lc 0 title "WALE c2"'

path_fwal055wal055='"fwal055wal055/rep16/stat_coupe"'
path_fwal055wal055_c2='"fwal055wal055_c2/rep20/stat_coupe"'

list="fwal055wal055 fwal055wal055_c2"
plot for [i in list] @path_.i u 1:(\$2/${Utau[${i}]}) @format_.i
EOFMarker
```

I would like to obtain something equivalent to:

```
plot @path_fwal055wal055 u 1:(\$2/${Utau[${i}]}) @format_fwal055wal055,\
@path_fwal055wal055_c2 u 1:(\$2/${Utau[${i}]}) @format_fwal055wal055_c2
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue ?

Thank you very much,
Martin

Comment: After your comment to my answer and your modified question I'm even more confused than before. Could you maybe please describe in words what you have and what you want? I don't know `awk`, so my guess would be that you have a list of files in the same directory and want to extract from each of them the value of the 5th row of the 1st column and with these values normalize the 2nd column of other related files which are in different directories. Please correct me if I'm wrong. This could also be achieved without using `awk`.

Comment: You're wright. I corrected the first message to explain it in detail. `awk` is a bash command to get the value of Utau. Could you explain me how to get the value of Utau without using `awk` knowing that the values of Utau (Utaufwal055wal055 and Utaufwal055wal055_c2) are localised in separated files (file_fwal055wal055 and file_fwal055wal055_c2) which are different from the plot files "stat_coupe" ? 
I thought to : `stats "file_fwal055wal055" every ::5::5 u $1 nooutput`
But I do not see how to put it inside the for loop in order to specify the iteration fwal055wal055 or fwal055wal055_c2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `help sprintf`, `help words` and `help word`.
I would create two strings with the same number of items and then combine them with `sprintf()`. From gnuplot 5.2 on you could also do it with arrays.

```
# Version 1
PATHS = '"fwal055wal055/rep16/stat_coupe" "fwal055wal055_c2/rep20/stat_coupe"'
FILES = "fwal055wal055 fwal055wal055_c2"

plot for [i=1:words(FILES)] sprintf("%s_%s",word(PATHS,i),word(FILES,i)) u 1:2
```

or you could define a function for your filenames to keep the plot command short and readable.

```
# Version 2
PATHS = '"rep16/stat_coupe" "rep20/stat_coupe"'
FILES = "fwal055wal055 fwal055wal055_c2"

myFilename(i) = sprintf("%s/%s_%s",word(FILES,i),word(PATHS,i),word(FILES,i))

plot for [i=1:words(FILES)] myFilename(i) u 1:2
```

**Addition** (after some clarifications...)

If I understand your question now correctly, the following code should do the job.
For the extraction of the `UTAUS` you do a separate loop before plotting and store the extracted values in a string. During plotting you get these values back via `word(UTAUS,i)`. Since you do the mathematical operation `column(2)/word(UTAUS,i)`, gnuplot will interpret them as number. Check `help words`, `help word`, `help sprintf`, `help every`.

**Code:**

```
### extract and normalize in a loop with individual files and directories
reset session

FILES  = 'fwal055wal055 fwal055wal055_c2'
DIRS   = 'rep16 rep20'
TITLES = '"WALE" "WALE c2"'   # if you have spaces you need to put it into double quotes
UTAUS   = ''

# define functions for better readability
myExtractionFile(i) = sprintf("file_%s",word(FILES,i))
myDataFile(i) = sprintf("%s/%s/stat_coupe",word(FILES,i),word(DIRS,i))
myTitle(i) = word(TITLES,i)

# define point or line appearance. Add more if you have more files
set style line 1 pt 1 ps 1.0 lc 0
set style line 2 pt 2 ps 1.0 lc 1

# extract the UTAUs
do for [i=1:words(FILES)] {
    set table $Dummy
        plot myExtractionFile(i) u (utau=$1) every ::4::4 w table   # extract value row 5, column 1 (not counting header lines)
    unset table
    UTAUS = UTAUS.sprintf(" %g",utau)   # append the extracted value as string
}

plot for [i=1:words(FILES)] myDataFile(i) u 1:(column(2)/word(UTAUS,i)) ls i title myTitle(i)
### end of code
```

Comment: Thank you @theozh. Nevertheless, my issue is not limitated to paths. The values of the for loop must be strings in order to get the value of "Utau_fr[${i}]" (I precised my issue by editing the 1st message).
Is there a solution to first combine "path_" and "i" (path_.i with i=fwal055wal055 for instance) and then take the value of this new string thanks to the macro symbol "at" (path_fwal055wal055 is know) ? When I write "at"path_.i Gnuplot try to get the value "at"path_ which does not exist. Is that possible to do something like "at"(path_.i) ?

Comment: It does not work to change the value of an @ macro inside a bracketed clause, notably including the bracketed clause of an iteration loop.  As theozh noted, you can evaluate the string using sprintf instead.  As a side note, you could change the directory separately from changing the file name by using the command `set loadpath "/new/directoryname"`.

Comment: Thank @Ethan. 
My problem is that if I use the solution proposed by theozh, I cannot  normalize the results of the simulation fwal055wal055 by Utaufwal055wal055 and by Utaufwal055wal055_c2 for the simulation fwal055wal055_c2.

Secondly, I do not succeed to an array with the format specifications in the same way as proposed by theozh: 

`PATHS = '"fwal055wal055/rep16/stat_coupe" "fwal055wal055_c2/rep20/stat_coupe"'`
`FILES = "fwal055wal055 fwal055wal055_c2"`
`FORMAT=''pt 1 ps 1.0 lc 0 title "WALE"' 'pt 2 ps 1.0 lc 0 title "WALE c2"''
`
My issue is due to quote surrounding.